# Why \ref{} gives (null)?

Tags: cross-referencing

I label an equation with: `\label{x}`.
I refer to it with: `\ref{x}`.
But my output gives: "(xnull)" rather than the expected "(x)".
Any suggestions?

A MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{array}
\def\null{{\rm null}\,}
\begin{document}
\title{MWE}
\maketitle

Consider ...
\begin{equation}
  \label{restriction}
  1=1
\end{equation}
Equation (\ref{restriction}) ...
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).  It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem.

While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: BTW, the expected output would be `1` (the equation number), not `x`, and you need to run `pfdlatex` twice.  But this does not explain why you get `(null)`. If you got `(xx)` that would make sense as that is the output upon first run.

Comment: Thanks Peter. Yes I am expecting (1) but getting (1null).

Comment: I will try to compose a MWE. Sorry for the clumsiness, this is my first time using SE...

Comment: MWE is below. I can tell now that the problem is with the command: \def\null{{\rm null}\,} and fix it. But for future reference would be nice to know why this is causing the mentioned behavior? Here is the MWE: \documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{array}


\def\null{{\rm null}\,}

\begin{document}

\title{MWE}
\maketitle

Consider ...
\begin{equation}\label{restriction} 
 1=1
\end{equation}
Equation (\ref{restriction}) ... 
\end{document}

Comment: Please add the code to your question instead of posting it as a comment. BTW, why did you define `\null` like that. Commenting `\def\null{{\rm null}\,}` resolves the issue.

Comment: Will do so next time. I don't know why \null is defined this way. I am just helping a friend who had problem with this...thanks:)

Comment: @Jonathan Your friend would be better served with `\DeclareMathOperator{\Null}{null}` (requires `amsmath` that's already loaded anyway), of course using `\Null` in place of `\null` in the document). A definition `\def\Null{{\rm null}\,}` would be wrong in many respects.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that with

```
\def\null{{\rm null}\,}
```

you are overriding the defaulf definition of the standard LaTeX command `\null`:

```
\def\null{\hbox{}}
```

and this will cause problems everywhere `\null` is used, for example in the kernel command `\@setref` used to reference a label (this explains the presence of the superfluous "null" in your example):

```
\def\@setref#1#2#3{%
\ifx#1\relax
\protect\G@refundefinedtrue
\nfss@text{\reset@font\bfseries ??}%
\@latex@warning{Reference `#3' on page \thepage \space
undefined}%
\else
\expandafter#2#1\null
\fi}
```

Is not a good idea to redefine kernel commands, unless you know what you are doing.

Had you used `\newcommand` to attempt the redefinition instead of `\def`, you would immediately obtained an error message informing you that `\null` is already defined. That's one of the advantages of using `\newcommand` over `\def`.

To define your own command,  choose a string which doesn't correspond to an already existing name; using the prefix "my" or using some capital letter in the name are usually good naming strategies.